# EF Core 3.0 Stored procedures custom view model

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-3.0, ef-core-3.0

i upgraded from .net Core 2.1 to 3.0, but i cant get my stored procedures working, so here is what i have.

i am having a few sp which return data from many different tables, so i created a class with all the custom fields that will be returned, and inside the context class i map them.

in 2.1 i did it like this.

```
public DbQuery<ProductByKeyword> ProductBriefInfoModel { get; set; }


builder.Query<ProductByKeyword>();
```

and in 3.0 i changed it to.

```
public DbSet<ProductByKeyword> ProductBriefInfoModel { get; set; }

builder.Entity<ProductByKeyword>().HasNoKey();
```

now this is not working with an error that i need to add migration, and upon adding migration i see that ef core is creating a table for this, so i see that something is wrong here, can anyone guide me where i am wrong? i dont have any view or table in my db for this, its just a sp that will return results and i want to get them into a model.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting my list repeated in ASP.net core as in custom model I put `[key]` so using `modelBuilder.Entity<ProductByKeyword>().HasNoKey();` resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve it, here is what I did.

1. changed the code back to the old way and saved it.
2. cleaned solution, and build again.
3. changed the code to the 3.0 version.
4. cleaned solution, and build again.

And now I don't get any errors anymore about adding migration.